# Problem while Invoking a webservice?

Tags: c#, vb.net, webservice-client

I am invoking a webservice and got this error..Do anyone know what is the exact problem...

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail. ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: An error occurred when verifying security for the message.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.ProcessReply(Message reply, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState correlationState, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 

at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
at IVWSecurityServices.addRole(String rolename, String roledesc)
at VWSecurityServicesClient.addRole(String rolename, String roledesc) in D:\NEC\App_Code\proxy.vb:line 312
at ProvisionService.addRole(String Customercode, String Customername) in D:\NEC\App_Code\ProvisionService.asmx.vb:line 59
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have not supplied any or correct authentication with your request.

Have you read the documentation on the WebService you are calling? Does it mention authentication at all?

Are you responsible for both the client and the server? If so how have you configured the server?

For a more exact answer we would need to know what service you are calling and how that is configured.

Comment: Dim objClient As VWSecurityServicesClient = New VWSecurityServicesClient("WSUserName")
            objClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "adminuser"
            objClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "****"
            objClient.addRole(Customercode, Customername)

Comment: Are you connecting to a public webservice? if so can you please provide links. If you are connecting to a private webservice what is providing the webservice and how is the sercirty configured? e.g. IIS/.Net/.ASMX or Apache/Tomcat/Axis2 or ...